# What's the purpose of implementing the IDisposable interface?

Tags: c#, idisposable

What's the purpose of implementing the IDisposable interface?  I've seen some classes implementing it and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your class creates unmanaged resources, then you can implement IDisposable so that these resources will be cleaned up properly when the object is disposed of.  You override Dispose and release them there.

Comment: It should also be implemented if the class is holding on to managed objects that in turn hold onto unmanaged resources (or hold onto other managed objects that ... and so on). There's no unmanaged resources to clean-up, but having a `Dispose()` that calls `Dispose()` in turn, means the ultimate holder of unmanaged resources gets cleaned up.

Answer (score 5):

When your classes makes use of some system resource, it's the class' responsibility to make sure the resource is freed too. By .Net design you're supposed to do that in the Dispose method of the class. The IDisposable interface marks that your class needs to free resource when it's no longer in use, and the Dispose method is made available so that users of your class can call it to free the consumed resources.

The IDisposable method is also essential if you want auto clean-up to work properly and want to use the using() statement.

Answer (score 3):

As well as freeing unmanaged resources, objects can usefully perform some operation the moment they go out of scope. A useful example might be an timer object: such objects could print out the time elapsed since their construction in the Dispose() method. These objects could then be used to log the approximate time taken for some set of operations:

```
using(Timer tmr=new Timer("blah"))
{
    // do whatever
}
```

This can be done manually, of course, but my feeling is that one should take advantage wherever possible of the compiler's ability to generate the right code automatically.

Answer (score 2):

It all has to do with the garbage collection mechanism. Chris Sells describes garbage collection, finalizers, and the reason for the Dispose pattern (and the IDisposable interface) [episode 10 of .NET Rocks!](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=10) (starting about 34 minutes in).

Comment: It doesn't really have much of anything to do with the gc mechanism, aside from finalisation not normally being necessary if you've successfully disposed. Pretty tenuous connection.

Comment: It absolutely has to do with garbage collection. Without the Dispose pattern, cleanup of unmanaged resources would have to be done in the Finalizer. More objects would survive initial collection and be moved into Gen 1 which extends their lifetime and adds more work to the overall collection process.

Comment: And this is more closely related to garbage collection than every single line of code that creates or uses an object, how?

Comment: Because most objects don't use unmanaged resources so they don't implement a Finalizer. Objects that don't implement a Finalizer don't need to put on the Finalization Queue and thus do not survive a collection.

Comment: Not all objects that implement `IDisposable` have a finalizer either. Not all that do deal with it there (`SqlConnection` inherits a finalizer, but calls `GC.SuppressFinalize` in its constructor as it will never be put in a state where its finalizer needs to be called). An object may call `GC.SuppressFinalize` on a `Close` and `GC.ReRegisterForFinalize` on an `Open`). `IDisposable` is precisely about providing a consistent interface on clean-up that is **not** handled by garbage collection, finalizers about making sure the former happens before the latter when vital, and GC about memory.

Answer (score 1):

Many objects manipulate other entities in ways that will cause problems if not cleaned up.  These other entities may be almost anything, and they may be almost anywhere.  As an example, a Socket object may ask another machine to open up a TCP connection.  That other machine might not be capable of handling very many connections at once; indeed, it could be a web-equipped appliance that can only handle one connection at a time.  If a program were to open a socket and simply forget about it, no other computer would be able to connect to the appliance unless or until the socket got closed (perhaps the appliance might close the socket itself after a few minutes of inactivity, but it would be useless until then).

If an object implements IDisposable, that means it has the knowledge and impetus required to perform necessary cleanup actions, and such actions need to be performed before such knowledge and impetus is lost.  Calling IDisposable.Dispose will ensure that all such cleanup actions get carried out, whereupon the object may be safely abandoned.

Microsoft allows for objects to request protection from abandonment by registering a method called Finalize.  If an object does so, the Finalize method will be called if the system detects that the object has been abandoned.  Neither the object, nor any objects to which it holds direct or indirect references, will be erased from memory until the Finalize method has been given a chance to run.  This provides something of a "backstop" in case an object is abandoned without being first Disposed.  There are many traps, however, with objects that implement Finalize, since there's no guarantee as to when it will be called.  Not only might an object be abandoned a long time before Finalize gets called, but if one isn't careful the system may actually call Finalize on an object while part of it is still in use.  Dangerous stuff.  It's far better to use Dispose properly.